# Setting Http Custom Header in REST Api Magento2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I want to set a custom Http header in my response in a Magento2 REST Api. I did the following:

```
class Review implements ReviewInterface {

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response) {

       $this->response = $response;

    }
```

And in my function I set it using:

```
$this->response->setHeader('X-rating-summary', $product_rating , true);
```

However I'm not getting the custom header in the response. Not sure what im missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just ran in to this as well. It seems the `\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface` class (usually injected as the `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http` class) only works for normal page requests.

If you are making your own [REST API service](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html) endpoint with the `webapi.xml` method, Magento uses a different Response object: `Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest`. You'll need to inject it like so:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response $response
) {
    $this->_response = $response;
}
```

Now this works correctly for me:

```
$this->_response->setHeader('X-rating-summary', $product_rating, true);
```